# missing metatag description bing

Tags: html, css, seo

I'm the owner of SafetyStore.com and currently rolling over my site from sparkpay to 3dcart.

Updating info with Bing and the test says that my site is missing the Title metatag and Description metatag. When I check the code, they are at line 276 and 282 on the main page. Do I have a syntax error I'm just missing? The site is showing the title properly. The two below blocks of code are from the Meta tags of the website. Here I'll show the error that bing was specifically providing in their SEO Analytics.
[Link to Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8kBS.png)

Do these need to post much higher on page?

```
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Safety Store® Provides: Safety kits First 
Aid Kits, Medical Supplies, Emergency Preparedness Kits and Disaster 
response products for home, Business & Gov">

 <title>SafetyStore.com  - Improving Your Safety Since 1995</title>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO. Some SEO questions are on-topic on the Web Masters site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<title>` and `<meta name="description">` tags are in the `<head>` section of your HTML document, and not the `<body>`. If these *are* in the head, I can see no reason why Bing would give you those errors. The reason why it still shows you the title and description like normal, when browsing the page, is because `<title>` can still work, even in the body. But, SEO tools and page-checkers will complain if it's not in the head.

I don't imagine lines 276 and 282 are in the `<head>`. Another thing that might help (but you might have this already)...

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I've noticed this helps with web crawlers and indexing.